# How to get difference of response received time and request made time

Tags: android

i need a difference between response recieved time - request made time.it should print the difference on the screen.for now it shows a button and if we click that button it prints response time stamp.

[image: The result for now]

Xml code below for the reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainacivity class code for reference

```
package com.example.volleydemo;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button Click;
    TextView responseText, timerText, timeLast;
    int clickCount = 0;
    Date endTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        responseText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        timerText = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        timeLast = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button) {
            timerText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timeLast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss aa");
            String differenceTime = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
            timeLast.setText("Current API call Time : " + differenceTime);
            String diff = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(currentTime.getTime(), endTime.getTime(),
                    DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS).toString();

            String lastSeen = dateFormat.format(endTime);
            timerText.setText("Last call was done at : " + lastSeen +
                    "\nLast API Call was done before : " + diff + " ago");
            endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }

        int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 200);

        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + randomInt,
                null, response -> {
            try {
                responseText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "the response is" + response.getString("title"));

                responseText.setText(" ID" + response.getString("id") + "\n Title-" +
                        response.getString("title") + "\n Completed-" +
                        response.getString("completed") + "\n User ID"
                        + response.getString("userId") + "\n");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

Build.gradle file for the reference

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.volleydemo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This-

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button Click;
    TextView responseText, timerText, timeLast;
    Date endTime;
    long startTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        responseText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        timerText = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        timeLast = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button) {
            timerText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            timeLast.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeLast.setText("Request made at : " + getDate(startTime, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS"));
            int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 200);
            RequestQueue requestQueue;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + randomInt,
                    null, response -> {


                try {
                    timerText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    timeLast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    timerText.setText("Request Completed within : "

                            + convertSecondsToHMmSs(elapsedTime));

                    responseText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    responseText.setText(" ID" + response.getString("id") + "\n Title-" +
                            response.getString("title") + "\n Completed-" +
                            response.getString("completed") + "\n User ID"
                            + response.getString("userId") + "\n");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long seconds) {
        long s = seconds % 60;
        long m = (seconds / 60) % 60;
        long h = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
        return String.format("%d Minute:%02d Second:%02d MilliSecond", h, m, s);
    }

    public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat) {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```